# Anchor link in JSFiddle result window

Tags: html, scroll, anchor, jsfiddle

Is there a way to link my JSFiddle from an external site so the result window is scrolled to an anchor?

Example: I want [this fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/uX7pc/) with the result window scrolled down to the red paragraph with `id="anchor"`

Can I do that without using JS in the fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link directly to the iframe display page, with the ID appended: http://fiddle.jshell.net/webtiki/uX7pc/show/#anchor

Still looking for an integrated solution.